# Sort array Given an array A, check if it is sorted in non-decreasing order or not

Tags: sorting

Using Java

Given an array A, check if it is sorted in non-decreasing order or not.

Non-decreasing order means that the numbers in a sequence can stay the same or increase, but they cannot decrease.

Input Format

The first and only argument contains an integer array A.

Output Format

Return 1 if array is sorted else return 0.

Example Input

Input 1:

A = [1, 2, 2]

Input 2:

A = [1, 2, 1]

Example Output

Output 1:

1

Output 2:

0

Example Explanation

Explanation 1:

We can see that the array elements are in non-decreasing order.

Explanation 2:

Second element is greater than the third element thus array is not in ascending order, hence not sorted.
Pls help me this code I don't know answer how to solve it .

I try for loop with in case use if else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify the language of your program but assuming you are doing it in C, it would looks like that :

```
int is_sorted(char *array)
{
    for (int i = 0, array[i + 1] != '\0', i++) {
        if (array[i + 1] < array[i])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This programm will loop on your array that you give as parameter. If the next number `array[i + 1]` is less than the actual number `array[i]` return 0. If this condition is not met we exit the loop at the end of the array and return 1 (true).

Comment: Java programming pls full code

Answer (score 0):

### PYTHON

```
def is_sort(a):
    f = True
    for i in range(len(a) - 1):
        if a[i] > a[i + 1]:
            f = False
            break
return f
```

### C++

```
bool is_sort(vector <int> a) {
    bool f = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
            f = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return f;
}
```

Something like this...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code in Java. It works the same as the code in C i've provided above.

```
public static int isSorted(char[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i + 1] < array[i]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Have a nice day !